# combine multiple mustache templates, then render HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

I'd like to integrate multiple mustachejs templates into a larger parent template. I'd like to do this so I have the option to replace one of the children later using just the child template. I'm trying to figure out how best to compile each template, then join them, then replace one of the children. I can build the templates normally using my primitive knowledge of mustache, but I don't know how to "combine" them. Ideally it would be done before any of them was rendered on the page, since the objects which populate them are ajax requests and may come back at different times. I wouldn't want one "module" to show up, then half a second later another module show up. How can I accomplish this. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ePehk/)

```
<!--templates-->
<script type="text/html" id="parent">
    <div style="color:blue">
        AGE: {{age}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="child1">
    <div style="color:green">
        AGE: {{age}}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="child2">
    <div style="color:gray">
        AGE: {{age}}}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="replacement">
    <div style="color:red">
        AGE: {{age}}}
    </div>
</script>



//javascript
//info for templates
var parent_obj = {"age":"adult"};
var child1_obj = {"age":"youngest"};
var child2_obj = {"age":"eldest"};
var replacement_child_obj = {"age":"brand new"}; 

//get templates
var parent_src = $("#parent").html();
var child1_src = $("#child1").html();
var child2_src = $("#child2").html();
var replacement_src = $("#replacement").html();

//make 3 compiled templates
var parent_temp = Handlebars.compile(parent_src);
var child1_temp = Handlebars.compile(child1_src);
var child2_temp = Handlebars.compile(child2_src);


//"somehow" combine first  3 into one template

//render HTML on page
$("body").append(/*rendered template*/);


//wait a bit and then replace child1 with replacement template
var t = setTimeout(function(){

    var replacement_temp = Handlebars.compile(replacement_src);
    //"somehow" insert into already rended HTML

},1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you combine the template text prior to compiling them? That seems like the best approach to me. In this way, you can manipulate the template strings, then have one compiled function that you populate when all the data has arrived, adding the resulting element to your document.

Comment: Thank you. This is not working for me however. The template isn't rendering. http://jsbin.com/qolokace/1/edit

Comment: This is working slightly better actually, but I still can't get the child content to append to the div within the script#parent tag. `$("#parent div")` and `$("#parent").find("div")` both return empty sets. Any ideas? http://jsbin.com/qolokace/5/edit